# Почему происходит ошибка с роутами в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Роуты:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
});
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    public function register(Request $req)
    {
        return 'dd';
    }
}
```

Путь контроллера:

[image: Путь контроллера]

В Postman я прописываю путь `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register` и метод post. Но возникает ошибка:

> Error: Class "App\Http\Controller\Controller" not found in
> file
> C:\Users\krash\Documents\FullStack_Backend\Laravel\laravel-itl\app\Http\Controllers\AuthController.php
> on line 7

**Что я делаю не так?**

Comment: Может `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте по другому роут прописать

```
Route::post("/register", "AuthController@Register");
```

В AuthController поменяйте название функции register на **R**egister
И поменяйте `namespace App\Http\Controller; -> namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

И обязательно почистите через терминал `php artisan optimize && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan view:clear`